# Zakat and Interest Free Forex Trading

Tags: halal-haram, sharia, riba, zakat, trading

I have two questions.

1- I have deposited a certain amount with a developer in a European country to get the immigration as per the laws of that European country. The rule is that the money will stay with the developer for a period of 5-6 years during which he will use that money to develop some real estate. After a period of 6 years, if the immigration department of that country award me immigration based on the amount of investment I have made and their other criteria/ rules then I will get my deposited money back after 6 years.

My question is that do I have to pay Zakat on this money till the time its with the developer and not in my possession?

2- Second question is related to forex/ commodity trading. If the broker offers me a leverage which has no swap or interest charges then can I use leverage to do commodity or forex trading?

Comment: First one sounds like a scam to me, do your due diligence.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To make yourself familiar with our site and model I strongly recommend you to take the [tour] and check our [help]. Please note that these are two questions asked in one post (see in our meta our position regarding [multi-question posts](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2965/why-we-should-avoid-asking-multi-question-questions)), please consider splitting your post so that each question can be handled in an adequate manner.